# What is the use of LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS?

Tags: android, frameworks, package, android-source, android-build

I want to update my Android.mk file in a package in order to build that new package, but I don't understand what the purpose of the `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS` is.

What does the `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS` do?

Comment: For me setting it to `samples` instead of `optional` led to it including the so libraries.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Correction:** 
Using user tag is no longer recommended. 
Instead,

```
Add "LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional"
Then add "LOCAL_MODULE" value to PRODUCT_PACKAGES section of product makefile.
```

**Original post:**

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS defines in which build flavor this module should be installed. 
Just give "user" tag, if you want the module to be installed in all of (user, userdebug, eng)

You can find full document [here](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#build-variants)

```
eng     This is the default flavor. A plain make is the same as make eng.

* Installs modules tagged with: eng, debug, user, and/or development.
* Installs non-APK modules that have no tags specified.
* Installs APKs according to the product definition files, in addition to tagged APKs.
* ro.secure=0
* ro.debuggable=1
* ro.kernel.android.checkjni=1
* adb is enabled by default. 

user    make user

This is the flavor intended to be the final release bits.

* Installs modules tagged with user.
* Installs non-APK modules that have no tags specified.
* Installs APKs according to the product definition files; tags are ignored for APK modules.
* ro.secure=1
* ro.debuggable=0
* adb is disabled by default.

userdebug   make userdebug

The same as user, except:

* Also installs modules tagged with debug.
* ro.debuggable=1
* adb is enabled by default.
```

Comment: If the user tag is no longer recommended. How can we mark a module appear only in eng build.

Comment: My understanding is that the "eng" tag will cause the module to appear in the eng build. The "userdebug" tag will cause it to appear in user debug builds, and the "optional" tag will cause it to appear in user builds IFF the module is listed in the PRODUCT_PACKAGES defined in vendor/<company>/proprietary/common/<product>/device-vendor.mk

Comment: ETA: if you don't want the module built *at all*, simply remove LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS entirely.

Comment: If you dont use `LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS`, it sets to `optional` by default and the module will be installed only if it declared in `PRODUCT_PACKAGES`.