# How do I add an optional Android module to my output image (full Android OS build)

Tags: android, build

How do I add modules that have been marked as optional to output image when building Android OS from source.

Say I want to add external/quake to the image when I build how do I do that?

this question [What is the use of LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496284/what-is-the-use-of-local-module-tags)
says:

```
Add "LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional"
Then add "LOCAL_MODULE" value to PRODUCT_PACKAGES section of product makefile.
```

where is the PRODUCT_PACKAGES section of the product makefile?

Comment: Have you looked at the makefiles in `device/vendor/product/` ? (e.g. device/samsung/toro/, or whatever vendor and product you're targetting).

Comment: Thanks @Michael I think that is what I was looking for. I will give it a try and let you know.  If it works you should post your answer as an answer not a comment so I can give you credit.