# what is modules tagged with user in AOSP build system

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to understand the android file system.
May I know what will happen with the AOSP compilation with "user" mode?

```
1.Installs modules tagged with the user.
```

What does this mean? What is the end behavior because of this?

```
2. Set the property ro.debuggable=0, turn off the application debugging function​
```

What does this mean? User can not debug an application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, see the doc about [build-variants](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#build-variants), and have a look at [What is the use of LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496284/what-is-the-use-of-local-module-tags)

For 2, see the comments about [ro.debuggable](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Build.java;l=1316?q=ro.debuggable&start=141):

```
    /**
     * Returns true if the device is running a debuggable build such as "userdebug" or "eng".
     *
     * Debuggable builds allow users to gain root access via local shell, attach debuggers to any
     * application regardless of whether they have the "debuggable" attribute set, or downgrade
     * selinux into "permissive" mode in particular.
     * @hide
     */
    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    public static final boolean IS_DEBUGGABLE =
            SystemProperties.getInt("ro.debuggable", 0) == 1;
```

For userdebug build, all application are debuggable, and for user build, only application with debuggable build variant can be debuggable. You can build debuggable build variant application by setting [android:debuggable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) to true in AndroidManifest.xml